# Webpack Including Files in Unexpected Directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have two webpack configs that are intended to target two different things in the following directory structure

```
./scripts/react/TestA.tsx
./scripts/typescript/TestB.tsx
```

They are seemingly isolated from each other with no imports in each but when I run the build with my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry:{
    typescript:[__dirname + "/../scripts/typescript/TestB.tsx"]
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
      {
        test:/\.tsx$/,
        exclude:[__dirname + "/../node_modules"],
        use:{ loader:"ts-loader" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It handles the build fine but it's bringing up errors in the folder I was not expecting

```
asset typescript.js 1.54 KiB [emitted] (name: typescript)
./scripts/typescript/TestB.tsx 69 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ***/scripts/react/TestA.tsx
```

Why is this happening and is there anyway to stop this? I tried to add it to the excludes options but it didn't seem to make any difference (I'm probably doing it wrong)

```
        exclude:[__dirname + "/../node_modules", __dirname + "/../scripts/react/"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack has nothing to do with this. It is the TypeScript type checker that is causing the issue. TypeScript compilation works on folder level. So, even if your Webpack doesn't really include that other file in the dependency graph, the TypeScript type checker will still type check all the files in the project.

TypeScript's type checks begins at the root folder where `tsconfig.json` file is detected. It checks all the files. That's the default behavior. You can change that behavior using [`baseUrl`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl) option.

As a quick solution, since you intend to generate two different builds, it means you can consider them as a **composite build** and it means you should have two projects in two different folders and use two different `tsconfig.json` files for two projects. By doing this, type checking of one project won't affect the other project.

Comment: Yes you're right. What I ended up doing is just making all of my Typescript syntax compliant with each other so that the tsconfig.json is happy with everything and then I can still use my separate webpack configs to handle each build in the same project.

Comment: @TheLovelySausage That can also work.